# pyodbc insert matrix into sql

Tags: python, sql-server, matrix, pyodbc

I have a matrix in python called ID_Mat. This matrix is composed by col = 12 and row = 288

I am trying to insert this matrix in a table in SQL server. I have already created the table in SQL, it is called project.mytable and each of the columns has a name like 'value1', 'value2'... and it is empty

What I am missing?

```
for col,row in ID_Mat():
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 
project.mytable([value1],[value2],[value3],[value4],[value5],[value6],[value7],[value8],[value9],[value10],[value11],[value12]) values ('pyodbc', 'ID_Mat')")
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Why are you inserting the name of DB-API, *'pyodbc'*, and name of matrix, *'ID_Mat'*, into table?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific. Are you talking about a `numpy.matrix`? If so, then tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for row, col in matrix:    
    sql = ("""INSERT INTO mytable (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, 
    value6, value7, value8...)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""")
    parameter_query = (row, col,...)
    cursor.execute(sql, parameter_query)
    conn.commit()
```

Try doing something similar to this
1.create your connection and cursor
2.Create your sql statement
3.Create your parameterized values
4.call cursor.execute with tuple of sql statement and parameter values
5.Commit with connection.
If you are doing this in a for loop dont close your connection or cursor in the for loop. You need it open. Either do it with a finally statement or a with statement.

Comment: But how do I refer so it gets the values from ID_Mat?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do but if you are asking how to pass in row col...
for row, col in matrix:
 parameter_query(row,col)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. Thank you so much for your help. I followed your syntax and I am getting:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: sql = ("""INSERT INTO mytable ([value1, value2...., value12) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""")
for row, col in table:
    parameter_query(row,col)

cursor.execute(sql, parameter_query)

cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()

Comment: for every value you are inserting you need to build your parameters with them. It would be the same thing as you passing in arguments and not having enough arguments.